# Hibernate createSQLQuery and Toad SQL query return different results - parameter problems?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm a newbie at Hibernate so excuse me if some of this is glaringly obvious but it's been a very, very long day. I am trying to create and execute a simple query in Hibernate and Toad/Oracle.

The Toad/Oracle sql reads:
    select
        count(*) 
    from
        fpps_owner.fee_claim_payment_lines l,
        fpps_owner.fee_claim_payments p
    where
        l.fee_claim_payment_id = p.fee_claim_payment_id   and
        p.claim_index = 87167895

The above returns 10 records, which is correct

The following Java code returns 0 records, which is NOT correct
    String sLinesAvailable =
    "select count(*) from " +
    "fpps_owner.fee_claim_payment_lines l, fpps_owner.fee_claim_payments p " +
    "where " +
    "l.fee_claim_payment_id = p.fee_claim_payment_id and p.claim_index = :id";

```
 Query qLinesAvailable = em.createNativeQuery(sLinesAvailable);
 qLinesAvailable.setParameter("id", "87167895");        // fails
 qLinesAvailable.setParameter("id", 87167895);    // fails


 List<Object> out = (List<Object>) qLinesAvailable.getResultList();
 BigDecimal x = (BigDecimal) out.get(0);
```

Returns 0 records. Using .getSingleResult() also returns 0 records.

What am I missing here?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing any malformed query errors, it seems like the parameter is not binding correctly.

To debug, I'd print out that SQL statement the line after you set the parameter. This is the only way you can see the SQL after the parameter is set in order to compare it with Toad.

What does your binding file look like? Maybe you have a different name in there for the ID, so it's not able to find it based on the name. Trying binding with the parameter's order value, just as a test.

This might give some ideas: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/

Best of luck! We've all been there :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try:

```
 (Number) query.getSingleResult();
```

Your query isn't returning a list, but rather just a count.

Good luck.